# Breaker compatibility

Tags: electrical-panel

I'm needing to replace a 20A single pole breaker in my Thomas & Betts, TBB20(20-40)CG Mod. 1 panel. Is there a site with a compatibility chart so I can buy the same type breakers?

I saw the post from a lady replacing her 30A water heater breaker and the comment had a link to a Pratt site, but the site doesn't load anymore.

[image: panel label]
[image: breakers]

Thank you

Update - You don't have to read below the following line. I am just adding a little bit of history to this issue.

---

My wife and I bought this place in November from San Antonio, TX (pressed for time and sight unseen by us. Our son, who lives near did look the place over, however doesn't know to look deeply into the electrical).

Anyway, the house (1998 Clayton mobile home) is outside of the city limits. It was moved onsite in 2006 and never registered in Florida (until we bought it). The owners built a roughly 20' x 30' addition to the mobile home.

From what I'm finding, the wiring would not pass code to the addition because they ran NM-B underground from the addition to the Service panel outside. They also ran NM-B to two sheds, where they commenced to splicing the two sheds in to the feeder and only taped the connections. Needless to say, the NM-b sheathing was damaged and when it rained hard it shorted out and tripped the 20A breaker. I've since dug (by hand no less) the trenches 24" deep and buried new UF-B to the shed and created a branch circuit to feed a 20A WR GFCI and branched to a 20A WR TR outlet. Both in outdoor weather resistant boxes.

I've since ran UF-B to the NM-B lines under the house and connected them inside gang boxes (14 inches above the ground) back to the meter panel.

If you've read all this then you know most of the story. Ha ha ha ha

Thank you all for your assistance.

[image]

Comment: If you haven't done these things yet, talk to us. We can save you a LOT of digging and/or some coin.  And avoid a code violation.

Comment: Example? Even though I already finished, I'd like to know where I could've saved. :)

Answer (score 8):

TLDR: For full-size breakers, use Eaton "CL" (CLassified) type - authorized by UL.  For double-stuff breakers, use Eaton's BRD which are marked "Type A" - authorized by your panel labeling.  Replace Square-D, green handle BR, and "no-name" tandem/quad breakers.

### Dangerous old breakers

Wow, you really do have a "breaker museum" in there.  As ThreePhaseEel advises, the Square D breaker needs to go. Even Square D forbids them in alien panels.

Your panel labeling says

[image]

The breakers starting with "TB" aren't made anymore. So all that's left is type "A", which are "double-stuffs" - tandem or quadplex.  Why is that outlier there?  It seems apparent that Thomas & Betts never developed their own "double stuff" breakers -- they simply *private-labeled* Challenger brand double-stuffs (as evidenced by careful comparison and the CSA file number being the same as Challenger).

Problem: Challenger breakers had huge problems with their safety certification, and the things are "fire starters".  They need to go.

Solution: Eaton BRD types are also labeled Type A!  There was nothing wrong with Challenger's bus design, and BRyant used **the same bus**.  Bryant relabeled it "BR", so they could exclude the faulty type C and A breakers.  Then, they asked UL to *cross-list* BR breakers for Type C and Type A, since they are, after all, the same bus.  *How convenient for us!*  BR became Cutler-Hammer BR and today it is Eaton BR.

However, the label does not allow the use of BR or Type C breakers.  (such as the Bryant BR with the green handle). It's probably fine, but it's a code violation.

For full-size breakers, you can use [Eaton CL type breakers](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/low-voltage-power-distribution-controls-systems/circuit-breakers/classified-circuit-breakers/ul-classified-replacement-circuit-breakers-sa00304001e.pdf) for a different reason: Eaton sent them to UL with a pile of legacy T&B panels, and UL tested them exhaustively and certified them as safe. They are UL-"Classified" for T&B panels.  CL breakers are available in 1-pole GFCI up to 30A, and 1-pole AFCI up to 20A.

### Common trip required

Whenever a 240V circuit carries a neutral wire, the breaker is required to have "common trip", so that an overload on one leg shuts off the other leg also. **That applies to the dryer and range**.

240V circuits without a neutral,  only need common maintenance shutoff... electric heaters, A/C, etc.

**Note the words "Non Common Trip" on the dryer and range quadplex**.  Those are the circuits that need it and they don't have it.

So this breaker must be changed to a common-trip version of that breaker.  Fortunately again the Eaton double-stuff line provides; you need a BQC230240.

### So I see a bit of a punch-list of work to do here.

- The labeled T&B breakers can stay.
- The Square D gets replaced with an Eaton CL220. *
- The green handle BR230 gets replaced with a CL230. *
- The QUADPLEX breaker in the middle needs common trip; Eaton BQC230240.
- All the "no-name" tandem breakers are the suspect Challenger type, and need to be replaced with "Type A" equivalents from the Eaton BR line.  That is BD1515 and BD2020.

#### * If Eaton CL is hard to find or prohibitive

If locating Eaton CL breakers proves burdensome: you can simply use Eaton double-stuffs instead.  For instance, the two 240V circuits (BR and HOM breakers) could be consolidated onto a single BQC220230 breaker (or if common trip is not needed, BQ220230).

Likewise, I apologize - I overlooked *your original* question.  Again a BR2020 could be used as its replacement.  This will give you a second breaker; just don't use it.

All empty holes MUST be filled!  Do not leave gaps in your panel! **The best hole filler is an actual breaker** connected to nothing. So save back a few that you're pulling out.   I would prefer the green handled BR, as it's the least wrong for this panel.

Comment: I wish to thank each and every one of you for your replies and information. @Harper - Reinstate Monica I am grateful for your answer since you listed the type I need to buy and the location it will replace. I plan to print the photo and mark each one with all of your replies just to keep it straight for me.

Comment: anyway to pm or message offsite? I have a question?

Comment: @KurtM - best you ask your follow-up here or as a new question so it can get the attention it deserves

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Is this one good to use in my panel?

BR 1-30 Amp 2 Pole and 1-40 Amp 2 Pole BQC (Common Trip) Quad Circuit Breaker
by Eaton

I found it on Home Depot's site.

Comment: Yeah, that's the BQC230240 Harper refers to in his answer

Comment: Thank you @ThreePhaseEel. It's almost half the price at HD than the other site I found it on. Dang, unavailable through HD...

Answer (score 3):

### The correct replacement breaker is a CL120

The correct replacement for a T&B breaker, generally speaking, is an [Eaton CL circuit breaker](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/low-voltage-power-distribution-controls-systems/circuit-breakers/classified-circuit-breakers/ul-classified-replacement-circuit-breakers-sa00304001e.pdf).  It's UL tested and *classified* to work in your panel, and also carries a factory warranty.  In your specific case, it's a CL120 you want, as you need a 1-pole, 20A breaker to replace what you have.

Note that you'll want to replace the alien HOM220 in the bottom left of your photo with a CL220 while you're in there; however, we're stuck keeping the other breakers (which look to be a mix of Challenger? and T&B) in service since there are no UL classified "double stuff" breakers.